# changing DataGridviewCellStyle on RowIndex 0

Tags: c#, datagridview

i use the following code to change the cell style in the CellEnter Event of a datagridview. but if i remove the if-statement all rows will be formated bold after databinding. any tip or advice ?

```
DataGridViewCellStyle oStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            oStyle.Font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9.25f, FontStyle.Bold);

            if (e.RowIndex > 0)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Style = oStyle;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Style = oStyle;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Style = oStyle;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Style = oStyle;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Style = oStyle;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Style = oStyle;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Style = oStyle;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Style = oStyle;
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Style = oStyle;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand right the behavior you expected. 
You can try to add the above code to the CellMouseClick event.